# Can JNDI be used by webapps to look up a logger?

Tags: java, logging, jndi

We have multiple webapps running in our container (Tomcat 6/7) and each webapp configures its own application-specific logging (to different log files).  There are certain events we need logged to a central log shared by all webapps.

We use JNDI to look up a datasource configured in Tomcat; is it possible to do the same thing with a logger, so when each web application starts it retrieves the shared container-level logger?

Comment: Generally objects have to be Serializable to go into JNDI which may cause you some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it should be possible, though I have not tried it myself. The logger is a Java object and you can store any Java object in a store that JNDI is aware of and JNDI should be able to retrieve it.

Comment: I'm not sure, though, if a logger returned to the webapp via JNDI would even log to the server's logger or just end up using the webapp's logger.

Comment: Right answer to my question, but it's a pretty useless question :)